# CSV mode in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Code mirror does not provide a CSV mode. 
A .CSV is a Comma Separated Value file (e.g. the ones we use in excel)

I would like to use codemirror as a editor for CSV files.

Can somebody suggest how to achieve this ?

(note I am not skilled enough to write my codemirror's mode)

Comment: what would you like to highlight there? commas?

Comment: @Templar pretty much. While some might argue that would be a tiny cosmetic change I think it would add lots of clarity.

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature, is there any solution here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really a really old post. Wanted a similar feature myself, try mathematica syntax highlighting on codemirror, it works pretty well with csv.